# Can the 'username' global variable in expression engine be used to select records from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, expressionengine

- I am trying to create a form for the parents in a school to book
  after-school care for their children through the school website,
  which is built using Expression Engine.
- Parents would log-in with their their family ID (a number
  matching the family record number in the database). Then, on the booking page, they would select from
  a drop-down list of their own children which child they would like to
  make the booking for.

**On the landing page after parent log-in, I have put the following PHP code:**

```
 <?php
    $_SESSION['familyid']='{username}';
    $_SESSION['family']='{screen_name}';
    ?>
```

> I did this on a separate page to the booking page because I thought
>   there might be an issue with global variables being parsed last in
>   ExpressionEngine. Then on the booking page, I have:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("server","database","password");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $sql = "SELECT ChildID, Child FROM Children WHERE FamilyID =       '".$_SESSION['familyid']."'";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

but this does not return any children.  If I give the session variable a valid number manually, it works, but I can't get the sql to work where the username has been passed to the variable.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Use the function print_r() on the $_SESSION variable to verify that the family ID is set and not null. Could also have it echo out the query to screen so can verify the variable as well. You should be able to cut and paste the output of echo directly into mysql for testing.

Comment: what is these things? `'{username}'` where those comes from? I thing, it should be `$_POST['username']` or `$_GET['username']` based on your form method.

Comment: I have tried echoing the query to screen, and it does have the family id number correctly.  The query appears exactly the same whether I pass the username to the session variable, or attribute it manually, but in the former case it doesn't return any children, in the latter it does.

Comment: Do you have PHP parsing stage on this template set set to input or output?  Needs to be 'output'.

Comment: It is set to 'output'. I think that's the default in Expression Engine, but anyway, I've just checked and it's definitely 'output'.

Comment: did you remember to `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Severe security issues with this - Ideally you want to keep it all in EE and **don't** enable PHP.

The correct way would be to have a module or plugin with the database credentials stored in the database.php config file, you can read a guide here:
http://www.99bugs.com/adding-external-databases-to-expression-engine-project/

Or there's an [add-on](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/external-entries) that will do this for you:

```
<ul>
  {exp:external_entries:select 
    hostname="mysql.deathstar.com" 
    username="deathstar_vader" 
    password="luk35dad" 
    database="deathstar_plans"  
    table="Children" 
    search:FamilyID="{username}"
    orderby="Child" 
    sort="asc"} 
    <li>
      Child ID = {ChildID}
      Child = {Child}
    </li>
  {/exp:external_entries:select}
</ul>
```

The examples from the plugin still have the insecure DB credentials in the template - but the comments mention that these can be stored in the config, but no details as to format, so a quick look into the plugin should shed some light on this.

Ideally you'd have the Children table in the EE database and do something like this native to EE using this [free add-on](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/session-variables-plugin) (EE2 only - not EE3) to save your session data on the landing page after login:

```
{exp:session_variables:set name="familyid" value="{username}"}
{exp:session_variables:set name="family" value="{screen_name}"}
```

Then on the booking page use the [query tag](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/query/):

```
<ul>
  {exp:query sql="SELECT ChildID, Child FROM Children WHERE FamilyID = '{exp:session_variables:get name="familyid"}'"}
    <li>
      Child ID = {ChildID}
      Child = {Child}
    </li>
  {/exp:query}
</ul>
```

But because the variables are actually always available, you don't need to save them in a session, as long as the user is still logged in:

```
<ul>
  {exp:query sql="SELECT ChildID, Child FROM Children WHERE FamilyID = '{username}'"}
    <li>
      Child ID = {ChildID}
      Child = {Child}
    </li>
  {/exp:query}
</ul>
```

**Edit** - Just downloaded and looked at the code for External Entries: there is no config settings, which is odd as it's simple to do, so could do with tweaking to make it even more secure.

Comment: This looks great.  I'll let you know how it goes.  Thank you.